# d3 change axis from left to top - issue with ticks

Tags: d3.js

I create very simple chart with 2 axis, bottom and left. I created a button who will change a state isVertical to true or not. So default state is true so when I click is changing to false and update my chart that left axis are going to top and bottom going to left (with correct scale). All is rendering correctly but only there is one issue. Ticks are under 45 degrees. Can anyone explain me why? Please take a look for that code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-shadow-6kwrk

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as d3 from "d3";

import "./styles.css";
const data = [
  ["January", 5],
  ["February", 7],
  ["March", 10],
  ["April", 14],
  ["May", 19],
  ["June", 23],
  ["July", 24],
  ["August", 22],
  ["September", 18],
  ["Obctober", 16],
  ["November", 12],
  ["December", 8]
];
const App = () => {
  const [isVertical, setIsVertical] = useState(true);
  const [widthWindow, setWidthWindow] = useState(window.innerWidth - 10);
  const [heightWindow, setHeightWindow] = useState(window.innerHeight - 50);

  const ref = useRef(null);
  const t = d3
    .transition()
    .duration(550)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear);

  useEffect(() => {
    const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 60, left: 60 };
    const innerWidth = widthWindow - margin.left - margin.right;
    const innerHeight = heightWindow - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const SVG = d3
  .select(ref.current)
  .attr("width", widthWindow)
  .attr("height", heightWindow);

const createChart = () => {
  const colors = ["red", "LIME", "blue", "DARKSALMON", "Silver", "FUCHSIA"];
  const allValuesForXAxis = data.map(e => e[0]);
  const allValuesForYAxis = data.map(e => e[1]);

  const xScale = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(allValuesForXAxis)
    .range(isVertical ? [0, innerWidth] : [0, innerHeight]);
  // .padding(0.05);

  const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.max(allValuesForYAxis), 0])
    .range(isVertical ? [0, innerHeight] : [0, innerWidth]);

  const yScaleTopAxis = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.max(allValuesForYAxis), 0])
    .range([innerWidth, 0]);

  //--------------------begin: bottom axis
  let translateAndRotate = "translate(20,20) rotate(60)";
  if (widthWindow > 600) {
    translateAndRotate = "translate(20,15) rotate(40)";
  }
  if (widthWindow > 800) {
    translateAndRotate = "translate(20,8) rotate(20)";
  }
  if (widthWindow > 1200) {
    translateAndRotate = "translate(0,0) rotate(0)";
  }

  const allGXaxis = SVG.selectAll("g.xaxis").data([
    "create only one element g so in this array is only one element"
  ]);

  allGXaxis
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "xaxis")
    .merge(allGXaxis)
    .transition(t)
    .call(isVertical ? d3.axisBottom(xScale) : d3.axisLeft(xScale))
    .attr(
      "transform",
      isVertical
        ? `translate(${margin.left},${heightWindow - margin.bottom})`
        : `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`
    )
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", isVertical ? translateAndRotate : "translate(0,0)");

  allGXaxis.exit().remove();
  //--------------------end: bottom axis

  //--------------------begin: left axis
  var allGYaxisL = SVG.selectAll("g.yaxisl").data([
    "create only one element g so in this array is only one element"
  ]);

  allGYaxisL
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "yaxisl")
    .merge(allGYaxisL)
    .transition(t)
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)
    .call(isVertical ? d3.axisLeft(yScale) : d3.axisTop(yScaleTopAxis))
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("fill", colors[1])
    .style("font-size", "1.5em")
    .style("font-weight", 900);

  // hardcoded fix issue for left axis but still is not like it should be:

  // allGYaxisL
  //   .selectAll("line")
  //   .attr("y2", isVertical ? 0 : -6)
  //   .attr("x2", isVertical ? -6 : 0);

  allGYaxisL.exit().remove();
  //--------------------end: left axis

  //--------------------begin: allRects
  // const gRects = SVG.selectAll("g.allrects").data([
  //   "create only one element g so in this array is only one element"
  // ]);

  // gRects
  //   .enter()
  //   .append("g")
  //   .attr("class", "allrects")
  //   .merge(gRects)
  //   .transition(t)
  //   .attr(
  //     "transform",
  //     isVertical
  //       ? `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top + innerHeight})`
  //       : `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})rotate(90)`
  //   );
  // gRects.exit().remove();

  // const allRects = gRects.selectAll("rect").data(allValuesForYAxis);
  // console.log(allRects)
  // allRects
  //   .enter()
  //   .append("rect")
  //   .attr("class", "rects")
  //   .merge(allRects)
  //   .transition(t)
  //   .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  //   .attr("height", (d, i) =>
  //     isVertical ? innerHeight - yScale(d) : innerWidth - yScale(d)
  //   )
  //   .attr("y", (d, i) =>
  //     isVertical ? yScale(d) - innerHeight : yScale(d) - innerWidth
  //   )
  //   .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale.bandwidth() * i)
  //   .attr("fill", (d, i) => colors[i]);
  // allRects.exit().remove();
  //--------------------end: allRects
};
createChart();
  }, [widthWindow, heightWindow, isVertical]);

  const changeLandscape = e => {
    isVertical
      ? (e.target.innerHTML = "click for horizontal")
      : (e.target.innerHTML = "click for vertical");
    setIsVertical(!isVertical);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={e => changeLandscape(e)}>click for vertical</button>
      <svg ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The normal etiquette is to post your code here, as externally hosted services tend not to keep code long term.

Comment: Hi Mikkel, post working code here in editor to works correctly, is almost impossible. So I implemented to external source where is more visible and easier to edit etc.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are rotating the the axis as well as the labels, where you set up the text, you are still chaining from the xaxis - I have added a comment in the code below to show you where...

```
allGXaxis
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "xaxis")
    .merge(allGXaxis)
    .transition(t)
    .call(isVertical ? d3.axisBottom(xScale) : d3.axisLeft(xScale))
    .attr(
      "transform",
      isVertical
        ? `translate(${margin.left},${heightWindow - margin.bottom})`
        : `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`
    )
// At this point you are still chaining functions on the xaxis, which is probably why the ticks get rotated as well
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", isVertical ? translateAndRotate : "translate(0,0)");
```

Comment: Hi Mikkel, thank you for trying helping me resolve issue. You can delete that part from code and see that this is not helping at all.